# org odt export: how to create a two columns section

Tags: org-mode, org-export, xml, libreoffice

In libreoffice I can insert a two column section. In org mode,
creating a two_columns page style and use

```
#+ATTR_ODT: :style "two_columns"
```

can produce a two column document, but org mode doesn't seem to have a section break like

```
# +SECTIONBREAK:
```

How can I switch from a two columns section to one column section?

Answer (score 0):

Does the image below capture what you want?

[image: Multi-column Section in ODT Export]

If yes, you can use the snippet below.  In the snippet, pay particular attention to the use of `#+begin_section ... #+end_section` and the use of `:style` ODT attribute.

Remember, for the snippet to work, you need to install the [The enhanced ODT exporter](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation) with `M-x package-install`.

In the

```
#+options: num:nil
#+options: toc:nil

#+odt_automatic_styles: <style:style style:name="OrgCustomSection" style:family="section">
#+odt_automatic_styles:  <style:section-properties fo:background-color="#ffff99" style:editable="false">
#+odt_automatic_styles:   <style:columns fo:column-count="2" fo:column-gap="2.498cm"/>
#+odt_automatic_styles:  </style:section-properties>
#+odt_automatic_styles: </style:style>

* A Plain Vanilla Section

#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non
turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum
accumsan nisl.
#+end_section

* A 2-Column Section

#+attr_odt: :style "OrgTwoColumnSection"
#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non
turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum
accumsan nisl.
#+end_section

* A 3-Column Section

#+attr_odt: :style "OrgThreeColumnSection"
#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non
turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum
accumsan nisl.
#+end_section

* A 2-Column Section in the ration 2:1

#+attr_odt: :style "OrgTwoColumnSection-2-1"
#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non
turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum
accumsan nisl.
#+end_section

* A 2-Column Section in the ratio 1:2

#+attr_odt: :style "OrgTwoColumnSection-1-2"
#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non
turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum
accumsan nisl.
#+end_section

* A Custom 2-Column Section 

#+attr_odt: :style "OrgCustomSection" :p-style "Preformatted_20_Text"
#+begin_section
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam
nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. 
#+end_section
```

The style configuration will look a bit overwhelming, at first. You can learn about it in

1. [Create a stylesheet for your OpenDocument files, and inline the XML definitions right in your Org file--Think HTML_HEAD, or HTML_HEAD_EXTRA but for ODT / DOCX files](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2020/06/21/create-a-stylesheet-for-your-opendocument-files-and-inline-the-xml-definitions-right-in-your-org-file-think-html_head-or-html_head_extra-but-for-odt-docx-files/)
2. [Applying custom styles through keywords](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Applying-custom-styles.html#Applying-custom-styles-through-keywords)

I am not sure what you mean by section breaks, or what you want to accomplish by it.  If you are still around, and care to elaborate a bit I can help.